# Can't attach bitmap image. Android

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, share

I saw other questions about this, tried their answers, but don't work.
I am trying to use the second method from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content).
(the second white bullet).
I save an image to applications internal memory, with appropriate permissions.
The image (bitmap) is saved successfully, but I can't attach it to a new intent, to share it.
Here is my code:

```
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("*/*");//Attach all types (images/text)

        FileOutputStream fos;

        try{
        fos = openFileOutput(myfilename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        mybitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.flush();
//Image is stored successfully (checked data/data/mypackage/files/myfilename)

           Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath(myfilename));
           shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // noth
        //Log.e(TAG, e.getStackTrace().toString());
    }

       shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "some text also");

        return shareIntent;
    }
```

Applications say that can't attach media items.
Gmail seems to attach item, but it shows nothing when mail send!

Also the uri.getPath returns me:
/data/data/mypackage/files/myfilename,
which is correct

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Edit:
Modified code to use sd card. And still don't get it to work:

```
        File imgDir;
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
imgDir = new File(
                android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                ".MyAppName/Images");
        else imgDir = MyActivity.this.getCacheDir();
        if (!imgDir.exists()) imgDir.mkdirs();

        File output = new File(imgDir, myFilename);

        OutputStream imageFileOS;
        try{
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
            imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(
                    uriSavedImage);
            bitmapBookCover.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90,
                    imageFileOS);


            imageFileOS.flush();
            imageFileOS.close();
//Again image successfully saved

            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriSavedImage);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // noth
        }
```

Comment: I think it's impossible to attache files from internal storage

Comment: tried with sd card, still cant get it to work

Comment: @Paschalis Did you succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Please try usiing **setData()** instead of **putExtra()**, here [android developer site - intent set data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setData%28android.net.Uri%29)

Comment: i am attaching text and image. it doesnt work. Tried shareIntent.setDataAndType(uri, Intent.EXTRA_STREAM), for image, and for text: shareIntent.setDataAndType(bookInfo, Intent.EXTRA_TEXT), with no luck